# which of the following points does the reflected ray pass?

Tags: geometry

Assume that the parabola $y^2 = 8x$ is the cross section of a parabolic reflector. A ray of light from a source at the point $(2, 0)$ strikes the point $(2, 4)$. Through which of the following points does the reflected ray pass?

$(a) (1, 4)$

$(b) (5, 4)$

I was visualizing the daigram,,,as  shown  below[image]

i got the answer (1,4)   is  its correct or not??

Any Hints/solution

Comment: If it is a reflector, how is the ray going to pass through it? Shouldn't it *reflect* the ray instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question itself is silly, because a ray is reflected by a reflector, and only one of the points is on the same side of the reflector as the incoming ray.

However, I think it is worth the effort to go into optics a bit, to see a couple of easy methods of examining rays and their reflections. In other words, this "answer" is for those who are more interested in *how to find out* than in the answer itself.

---

Another way to write the equation for the parabola
$$y^2 = 8 x$$
is
$$y = \pm \sqrt{ 8 x }$$
Because everything interesting occurs on positive $y$, it is enough for us to examine the upper half-space, i.e.
$$y = \sqrt{ 8 x } \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
The derivative of $y$ gives us the slope at each point:
$$\frac{d y}{d x} = \dot{y} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
Note that the angle at $x$ is the inverse tangent (arctangent) of the slope,
$$\phi(x) = \arctan(\dot{y}) = \arctan\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)$$
where $\phi = 0$ is horizontal, increasing values rotating counterclockwise in a right-handed coordinate system ($x$ right, $y$ up).

The rules for reflection is that the angle between the incoming ray and the surface normal is the same as between the outgoing ray and the surface normal, with the incoming and outgoing rays on different sides of the surface normal. This means that a vertical ray (towards positive $y$) hitting a slope $m$ will be reflected towards positive $x$ if $m \gt 0$, negative $x$ if $m \lt 0$, and back vertically towards negative $y$ if $m = 0$.

If a vertical ray towards positive $y$ hits a reflector with slope $m \gt 0$, the new ray will go towards positive $x$ with slope
$$m^\prime = \frac{m^2 - 1}{2 m} \tag{3}\label{NA3}$$

If we have a ray that starts from $x = 2$, $y = 0$ vertically (towards positive $y$), it hits the reflector at $y(2) = 4$. At that point, the slope of the reflector is $\dot{y}(2) = 1$ (and $\phi(2) = 45°$). Obviously, the outgoing ray is horizontal, towards positive $x$.

Let's consider a harder case: a ray that starts from $x = 3$, $y = 0$ vertically (towards positive $y$). It hits the reflector at $y(3) = \sqrt{24} \approx 4.899$. The slope at that point is $\dot{y}(3) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. Using $\eqref{NA3}$, we can calculate the slope of the ray reflected towards positive $x$ as $-\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}} \approx -0.2041$, i.e. slightly downwards, at an angle of about 11.5°.

---

The obvious question is, how is $\eqref{NA3}$ derived, then?

We use a right-handed coordinate system where $x$ increases right, and $y$ up. Zero degrees is towards $+x$, ninety degrees or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians is towards $+y$, 180° = $\pi$ radians is towards $-x$, and 270° = -90° = $\frac{3}{2}\pi$ = $-\frac{1}{2}\pi$ is towards $-y$.

The angle of the incoming ray is $\theta_i = -90° = -\frac{1}{2}\pi$. (This is the direction from which the ray is coming from, towards the reflecting surface.)

The angle of the normal of the reflecting surface with slope $m$ is $\theta(m) = \arctan(m) - 90° = \arctan(m) - \frac{1}{2}\pi$. (This must be in the same halfspace as $\theta_i$, i.e. within 180° of $\theta_i$.) I've chosen the surface normal to point outwards from the surface; note that some references, like the [Reflection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html) article on Wolfram Mathworld, choose a surface normal that points inside the surface.

Because the angle between the normal and the incoming ray is the same as the angle between the normal and the outgoing ray (the incoming and outgoing rays being on different sides of the normal), the angle of the outgoing ray is
$$\theta_o(m) = \theta(m) + \left ( \theta(m) - \theta_i \right ) = 2 \theta(m) - \theta_i = 2 \arctan(m) - \frac{3}{2} \pi$$
Because $\theta_o(m)$ is the angle, $\tan(\theta_o(m))$ is the slope:
$$m^\prime = \tan\left( 2 \arctan(m) - \frac{3}{2} \pi \right) = \frac{m^2 - 1}{2 m}$$

In the general case, it is easy to work with angles, although you must be careful with wraparound (i.e., -90° = +270° and such).

---

It is even easier if you work with unit vectors. (Unit vectors are vectors of length 1, i.e. sum of the components squared is always 1.) If you have a direction $(\chi, \gamma)$, the corresponding unit vector is
$$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\chi^2 + \gamma^2}} \left [ \begin{matrix} \chi \\ \gamma \end{matrix} \right ] = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
p_x &= \frac{\chi}{\sqrt{\chi^2 + \gamma^2}} \\
p_y &= \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\chi^2 + \gamma^2}} \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$

The unit vector corresponding to angle $\phi$ is obviously
$$\hat{r} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) \end{matrix} \right ] = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned} r_x &= \cos(\phi) \\ r_y &= \sin(\phi) \end{aligned}\right.$$
You can obtain the inverse using $\operatorname{atan2}$,
$$\phi = \operatorname{atan2}\left( r_y , r_x \right)$$
which is very similar to $\arctan\left(\frac{r_y}{r_x}\right)$, except $\operatorname{atan2}$ takes into account the signs of $r_y$ and $r_x$ and returns the angle in the correct quadrant (so its results vary from -180° to +180°, or 0° to 360°).

If you have a surface with slope $m$, its unit normal vector is
$$\hat{n} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}} \left [ \begin{matrix} m \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right ], &
\text{reflecting towards} \; +x \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}} \left [ \begin{matrix} -m \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ], &
\text{reflecting towards} \; -x \\ 
\end{cases}$$

If you have a light ray towards $\hat{r}$ that intersects a surface with normal $\hat{n}$, then $\hat{r} \cdot \hat{n} \lt 0$ (otherwise the ray intersects the back side of the reflector; if the reflector is two-sided and infinitely thin, you can simply negate both components of $\hat{n}$ to make it point the right way). Then, the outgoing ray vector is
$$\vec{R} = 2 \hat{n} \left ( \hat{r} \cdot \hat{n} \right ) - \hat{r} = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
R_x &= 2 n_x ( r_x n_x + r_y n_y ) - r_x \\
R_y &= 2 n_y ( r_x n_x + r_y n_y ) - r_y \\
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{4}\label{NA4}$$
which you should normalize to unit length to get the unit direction vector the reflected ray is going,
$$\hat{R} = \frac{\vec{R}}{\sqrt{\vec{R} \cdot \vec{R}}} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
\frac{R_x}{\sqrt{R_x^2 + R_y^2}} \\ \frac{R_y}{\sqrt{R_x^2 + R_y^2}} \end{matrix} \right ]$$
Note that in principle, the reflected vector $\vec{R}$ should be an unit vector if both $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{r}$ are unit vectors. In numerical calculations, rounding error always creeps in, so normalizing to unit length is either necessary, or at least warmly recommended.

If we apply these to the latter example above, then
$$\hat{r} = \left[\begin{matrix}0\\-1\end{matrix}\right], \quad
\hat{n} = \left[\begin{matrix}\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\\-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\end{matrix}\right], \quad \vec{R} = \left[\begin{matrix}\sqrt{\frac{24}{25}}\\ -\frac{1}{5}\end{matrix}\right] = \hat{R}$$
and the slope of the outgoing ray is $$\frac{R_y}{R_x} = \frac{-\frac{1}{5}}{\sqrt{\frac{24}{25}}} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{24}}$$
as we already found out earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reflector: the ray should remain on the same side of the parabola at all times.  One of the two points is on the same side as ray's source; the other is not.